# Древовидные структуры в java

Tags: java, структуры-данных

Пытаюсь понять что такое **Tree**. Кто нибудь может дать толковую статью где грамотно это описано?

Также хочу понять различия между **TreeMap**, **TreeSet** и **TreeList**. Если можно киньте ссылочку.

Answer (score 6):

В контексте `TreeMap`, `TreeSet` и `TreeList` приставка **Tree** указывает на внутреннее устройство коллекции. Во всех трёх случаях внутри у этих коллеуций бинарное дерево поиска (в первых двух случаях красно-чёрное, насчёт третьего точно не уверен). Класс [`TreeMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) представляет собой коллекцию, хранящую пары ключ-значение, причём при итерации по этой коллекции ключи перебираются в отсортированном порядке (в отличие от, например, `HashMap`, где порядок ключей не гарантируется). Класс [`TreeSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html) - это коллекция, хранящая набор уникальных элементов (попытки добавить повторяющиеся элементы игнорируются). Также при итерации элементы перебираются в отсортированном порядке. Оба этих класса входят в Collections Framework, стандартную библиотеку коллекций Java. Почитать про них можно в любой приличной книжке по Java (например, Хорстмана или Эккеля). Класс `TreeList` является частью Commons Collections, расширенной библиотеки коллекций, разрабатываемой Apache. Этот класс представляет собой список, оптимизированный для операций вставки и удаления элементов. Подробнее про него читайте в [документации](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-3.2.1/org/apache/commons/collections/list/TreeList.html).  Также можете почитать [статью](http://www.quizful.net/post/Java-TreeMap) про внутреннее устройство класса `TreeMap` и красно-чёрные деревья.

Comment: Замечательный ответ!

Я бы еще добавил, что Tree (дерево) применяется там где необходим быстрый поиск значения в каком-нибудь большом массиве данных. В частности, индексирование таблиц в БД часто ведется построением BTree дерева. Если рассуждать философски, то дерево это набор данных, в котором данные хранятся в некотором предварительно "немножко" сортированном виде.